# Looking for Multiple pattern on Multiple arrays

Tags: php, regex, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Oramen
    [1] => 20
    [2] => OT-301-FNS
    [3] => 40X40
)
Array
(
    [0] => LR-153-TKW
    [1] => Klaten
    [2] => Rectangular
    [3] => 
    [4] => 12x135x97
)
Array
(
    [0] => GN-187-TKW
    [1] => GARDEN
    [2] => LAMP
    [3] => POST
    [4] => A
    [5] => 30x30x130.JPG
)
Array
(
    [0] => BANDUNG
    [1] => ENTERTAINMENT
    [2] => TABLE
    [3] => LR-315-TKW
    [4] => 
    [5] => -
    [6] => 180x50x46.5
)`enter code here`
```

I want to remove all items that match the dimension fo the furniture. is it possible to do that using one regex expression? really apreciate the help

Comment: By items, do you mean the matching array key or the entire array with the matching dimension?

Comment: no just the array key with the dimension i want to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
foreach ($array_of_arrays as &$some_array) {
  $some_array = array_filter($some_array, function($el) { 
    return ! preg_match('#^\d+x\d+#i', $el);
  });
}
unset($some_array);
```

In other words, you filter each of these arrays with the function that tries to match its elements, one by one, with pattern...

```
`/^\d+x\d+/i`
```

... which means 'match the beginning of the string, then any number of digits, then `x` character, then any number of digits'. From what I've seen in your examples, this is a pattern to follow, as `^\d+x\d+x\d+` won't match '40X40' value.

Comment: it wont match 40X40 and any value with a parentheses before the digit

Comment: `  $space = explode(' ',$xname);
  

  $pattern_matched_array = preg_grep('/^\d+x\d+x\d+/i', $space);
  
  if(count($pattern_matched_array) > 0)
  {
   foreach($pattern_matched_array as $key => $value)
   {
    unset($space[$key]);
    
    
   }
   
  } 
  
  
  
  echo "<pre>";
        print_r($space);
        echo "</pre>";`

Comment: the values with 'X' actually is not fixed theres some arrays that have these value     [0] => OVAL
    [1] => EXTENDABLE
    [2] => TABLE
    [3] => GN-113-TKW
    [4] => 120-180X90X75
    [5] => GN-114-TKW
    [6] => 
    [7] => 150-200X100X75
    [8] => GN-151-TKW
    [9] => 180-240X120X75

Comment: Replace the pattern used with `'#^(?:\d+-)?\d+x\d+#i'` to reflect this.